# Add event handler from ClassA to an event called in ClassB

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am really stuck with how to use events in my app. I have two files:

```
RTimer.cs
SettingsForm.cs
```

I have a timer set up in `RTimer.cs` that initializes the timer and sets the interval and such.

I have a method in `SettingsForm.cs` that needs to do something every time the timer ticks. This file also has a method that sets the timers interval via a `SetTimer()` method in the `RTimer.cs`

I cant for the life of me figure out how to get the `Tick` event to call the method from the other class, or get the method in the other class to subscribe to the `Tick` event.

Comment: What Timer structure are you using that has the Tick event? [edit] ah windows forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this way :

```
class SettingsForm
{
    public void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class RTimer
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public void StartTimer(SettingsForm settingForm)
    {
        timer.Tick += settingForm.OnTimerEvent;
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly thank you. Events and Delegates are still a little confusing to me.

Comment: @coryrwest - yes they are! but once u understand them, c# is magic!